# rich:status onstop doesn't work for IE10

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, richfaces, internet-explorer-10

I'm using RichFaces 3.3.3. In main template I've a4j:status tag for all ajax request in application.

`<a4j:status id="ajax-status" 
    onstart="#{rich:component('processing')}.show()"
    onstop="#{rich:component('processing')}.hide()">
</a4j:status>`

Everything works fine in every browser except IE10. OnStop event just is not called.
I consider two solutions:
1. Find another library with similar component which will works fine in all browsers
2. Maybe in Javacript there is a way to detect all ajax requests are finished. I've found this kind of code, but only for jQuery requests.